# Flutter: showGeneralDialog does not share a context with the location that showGeneralDialog is originally called from

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog

#### Problem:

My showGeneralDialog-creation method looks like this:
(I'm animating the onShow and onPop of the dialog, that's why I use the transitionbuilder instead of the pagebuilder)

```
  void _showSignOutAlert(BuildContext context) {
    showGeneralDialog(
      barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
      transitionBuilder: (context, a1, a2, widget) {
        return Transform.scale(
          scale: a1.value,
          child: Opacity(
            opacity: a1.value,
            child: CustomWidget(),
          ),
        );
      },
      transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
      barrierDismissible: true,
      context: context,
      pageBuilder: (context, animation1, animation2) {
        return null;
      },
    );
  }
```

I'm calling `_showSignOutAlert()` from a StatelessWidget passing along the StatelessWidget-context in the parameter.

I'm using the Provider-package and defined the ChangeNotifierProvider-builder above the StatelessWidget which calls the `_showSignOutAlert()`

When trying to access the Provider from the `CustomWidget` created by `showGeneralDialog()`, it's says it couldn't find the Provider.

*From the flutter docs about showGeneralDialog():*

> This function takes a pageBuilder which is used to build the primary content of the route (typically a dialog widget). Content below the dialog is dimmed with a [ModalBarrier]. The widget returned by the pageBuilder does not share a context with the location that showGeneralDialog is originally called from. Use a [StatefulBuilder] or a custom [StatefulWidget] if the dialog needs to update dynamically. The pageBuilder argument can not be null.

#### Question:

I don't really get how I should proceed to be able to access the Provider from the `CustomWidget`?

Comment: You can get `provider` by this `Provider.of<>(context)`. Which you have already mentioned . So what is your question?

Comment: @Vrushi Patel Indeed, now it works, though maybe there is another way of reaching the context - of the widget calling the showGeneralDialog() - in the CustomWidget, other than passing it along as an argument to the CustomWidget. Maybe there isn't and my update is the only and correct answer.

Comment: @Vrushi Patel, I removed the update and put it as a possible answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

correct way :

```dart
void _showSignOutAlert(BuildContext context) {
  final CapturedThemes themes = InheritedTheme.capture(
    from: context,
    to: Navigator.of(
        context,
        rootNavigator: true,
    ).context,
  );

  showGeneralDialog(
    barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
    transitionBuilder: (context, a1, a2, widget) {
      return Transform.scale(
        scale: a1.value,
        child: Opacity(
          opacity: a1.value,
          child: widget,
        ),
      );
    },
    transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
    barrierDismissible: true,
    context: context,
    pageBuilder: (context, animation1, animation2) {
      return themes.wrap(Builder(
        builder: (context) => CustomWidget(),
      ));
    },
  );
}
```

pay attention to :

`CapturedThemes` and `themes.wrap`

Comment: Thanks ! That is definitely the way to go !

Answer (score 2):

put useRootNavigator  to false

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/showGeneralDialog.html

> The useRootNavigator argument is used to determine whether to push the
> dialog to the Navigator furthest from or nearest to the given context.
> By default, useRootNavigator is true and the dialog route created by
> this method is pushed to the root navigator.

Comment: Oh my god, you just save my day. I spent hours figuring out why the dialog not closing but it popping my page. I don't know why the context is different.

Answer (score 1):

I did manage to pass the context, by doing so:

```
  void _showSignOutAlert(BuildContext superContext) {
    showGeneralDialog(
      barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
      transitionBuilder: (context, a1, a2, widget) {
        return Transform.scale(
          scale: a1.value,
          child: Opacity(
            opacity: a1.value,
            child: CustomWidget(superContext: superContext),
          ),
        );
      },
      transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
      barrierDismissible: true,
      context: superContext,
      pageBuilder: (context, animation1, animation2) {
        return null;
      },
    );
  }
```

And then using the superContext in the CustomWidget to call `Provider.of<State>(superContext)`

But if anyone has another solution, I'd gladly hear it